# How do I convert an Elem (with lift:surround) to a LiftResponse?

Tags: templates, lift

I find myself needing to produce a LiftResponse, and I have an
existing piece of code that produces a Elem, inside of which is

stuff

How do I turn this into a LiftResponse? (I'm using Lift 2.2M1.)

Comment: I know this should be super simple, but I'm stuck. I've also asked on the Lift mailing list: I hereby promise to copy and paste any good answers here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Via the mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/liftweb/browse_thread/thread/6c8aeac0a0013af7?hl=en), David Pollak suggests

```
val r: Req = ... 
val myResponse: Box[LiftResponse] = 
for { 
  session <- S.session 
  template = TemplateFinder.findAnyTemplate("my_templates" :: "my_template" :: Nil) 
  response <- session.processTemplate(template, r, r.path, 200) 
} yield response
```

although that thread also tries to explain why what I was trying to do was a bit strange in the first place.